# websockets, asyncio and PyQt5 together at last. Is Quamash necessary?

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, pyqt5, python-asyncio

I've been working on a client that uses PyQt5 and the websockets module which is built around asyncio. I thought that something like the code below would work but I'm finding that the incoming data (from the server) is not being updated in the GUI until I click enter in the line edit box. Those incoming messages are intended to set the pulse for the updates to the GUI and will carry data to be used for updating. Is quamash a better way to approach this?  btw, I will be using processes for some other aspects of this code so I don't consider it overkill (at this point). 
This is Python 3.6, PyQt5.6(or higher) and whatever version of websockets that currently installs with pip.  https://github.com/aaugustin/websockets

The client:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import asyncio
import websockets
import sys
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe, Queue
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class ComBox(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self)
        self.groupBox.setTitle( "messages from beyond" )
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.groupBox)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.lineEdit.editingFinished.connect(self.enterPress)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def enterPress(self):
        mytext = str(self.lineEdit.text())
        self.inputqueue.put(mytext)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def updategui(self, message):
        self.label.setText(message)

class Websocky(QtCore.QThread):
    updatemaingui = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    def __init__(self):
        super(Websocky, self).__init__()
    def run(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(.1)
            message = self.outputqueue.get()
            try:
                self.updatemaingui[str].emit(message)
            except Exception as e1:
                print("updatemaingui problem: {}".format(e1))

async def consumer_handler(websocket):
    while True:
        try:
            message = await websocket.recv()
            outputqueue.put(message)
        except Exception as e1:
            print(e1)

async def producer_handler(websocket):
    while True:
        message = inputqueue.get()
        await websocket.send(message)
        await asyncio.sleep(.1)

async def handler():
    async with websockets.connect('ws://localhost:8765') as websocket:
        consumer_task = asyncio.ensure_future(consumer_handler(websocket))
        producer_task = asyncio.ensure_future(producer_handler(websocket))
        done, pending = await asyncio.wait(
            [consumer_task, producer_task],
            return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED, )
        for task in pending:
            task.cancel()

def start_websockets():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(handler())

inputqueue = Queue()
outputqueue = Queue()

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
comboxDialog = ComBox()
comboxDialog.inputqueue = inputqueue
comboxDialog.outputqueue = outputqueue
comboxDialog.show()

webster = Websocky()
webster.outputqueue = outputqueue
webster.updatemaingui[str].connect(comboxDialog.updategui)
webster.start()

p2 = Process(target=start_websockets)
p2.start()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The server:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import asyncio
import time
import websockets

# here we'll store all active connections to use for sending periodic messages
connections = []


#@asyncio.coroutine
async def connection_handler(connection, path):
    connections.append(connection)  # add connection to pool
    while True:
        msg = await connection.recv()
        if msg is None:  # connection lost
            connections.remove(connection)  # remove connection from pool, when client disconnects
            break
        else:
            print('< {}'.format(msg))

#@asyncio.coroutine
async def send_periodically():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(2)  # switch to other code and continue execution in 5 seconds
        for connection in connections:
            message = str(round(time.time()))
            print('> Periodic event happened.')
            await connection.send(message)  # send message to each connected client

start_server = websockets.serve(connection_handler, 'localhost', 8765)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.ensure_future(send_periodically())  # before blocking call we schedule our coroutine for sending periodic messages
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortly after posting this question I realized the problem.  The line

```
message = inputqueue.get()
```

in the producer_handler function is blocking.  This causes what should be an async function to hang everything in that process until it sees something in the queue.  My workaround was to use the aioprocessing module which provides asyncio compatible queues.  So, it looks more like this:

```
import aioprocessing

async def producer_handler(websocket):
    while True:
        message = await inputqueue.coro_get()
        await websocket.send(message)
        await asyncio.sleep(.1)

inputqueue = aioprocessing.AioQueue()
```

The aioprocessing module provides some nice options and documentation. And in this case is a rather simple solution for the issue.   https://github.com/dano/aioprocessing
So, to answer my question:  No, you don't have to use quamash for this kind of thing.